# Find a trail camera I put in a backcountry area far from reliable cell phone coverage

Tags: satellite-phones, trail-cameras

I want to put some trail cameras in a remote location in an area far from reliable cell phone coverage, and leave them there for several weeks to capture videos of wildlife.

I wonder how I will be able to return back and pick up my camera if I forget how to return to the same place?

What devices are used to accomplish this?

Comment: A GPS to mark where you put it in the first place?

Comment: GPS uses satellites, and is completely independent from cell phone coverage.

Comment: A real GPS, yes.  Cellular GPS needs the cell network to increase resolution speed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few methods possible:

Old school -

- Find where you are on the map
- Mark this location on the map
- Another option - mark to your camera using temporary trail markers (day-glo paint, flagging tape, even bent over ferns etc.) Just make sure you remove these marks once you are done.

Newer school -

- GPS tag using dedicated GPS, your GPS watch or Phone (some phones rely on cell-towers for GPS, but not all, check your model)
- Radio tag - like they do for animals. You need the kit to do this though.

Comment: Thank you @bob1

Answer (score 1):

If I was going to leave an object in the backcountry I would use a GPS to record the location of the object and add a Tile tracker (I haven't checked if there are other similar devices) to what I was leaving.  GPS will get me within range of the tracker.

They have a waterproof version of the tracker that you can stick to the outside of your camera.  If you can ensure the tracker is shielded from the weather you can use the non-shielded version, but I would not be inclined to use that in most weatherproof enclosures as the enclosure would muffle the sound if you activate it's noisemaker.  (The downside to the weatherproof version is that it's sealed--when the battery dies you throw it away.)  Unlike the radio tags bob1 is talking about this is mass produced consumer electronics and thus cheap.